# Webpack doesn't generate index.html

Tags: firebase, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue and firebase.

when I tired "npm run build" to deploy firebase hosting server I got this files

build.js, build.js.map, logo.png, profile.jpg

I'm wondering why it doesn't generate index.html

So I tired HtmlWebpackPlugin but it also didn't work.

here's my webpack.config.js

Thanks!

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
                'vue-style-loader',
                'css-loader'
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders: {}
                // other vue-loader options go here
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
},
performance: {
    hints: false
},
devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
        // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
    module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: '"production"'
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true
    })
])
}
// webpack.config.js
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        Vue: ['vue/dist/vue.esm.js', 'default'],
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        moment: 'moment',
}),
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       hash: true,
       filename: './dist/index.html' //relative to root of the application
   })
]
```

here's my package.json

```
 "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you don't export your last 2 plugins and specify html filename without `dist`, because `HtmlWebpackPlugin` should generate file relative to your `path`, here is fixed config:

```
    var path = require('path')
    var webpack = require('webpack')
    var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

    module.exports = {
        entry: './src/main.js',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            publicPath: '/dist/',
            filename: 'build.js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        'vue-style-loader',
                        'css-loader'
                    ],
                }, {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    loader: 'vue-loader',
                    options: {
                        loaders: {}
                        // other vue-loader options go here
                    }
                },
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        resolve: {
            alias: {
                'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
            },
            extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
        },
        devServer: {
            historyApiFallback: true,
            noInfo: true,
            overlay: true
        },
        performance: {
            hints: false
        },
        devtool: '#eval-source-map',
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                Vue: ['vue/dist/vue.esm.js', 'default'],
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                moment: 'moment',
            }),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                hash: true,
                filename: 'index.html'
            })
        ]
    }

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
        // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
        module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: '"production"'
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                sourceMap: true,
                compress: {
                    warnings: false
                }
            }),
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                minimize: true
            })
        ])
    }
```